# Why doesn't this regex capture group repeat for each match?

Tags: regex

I'm testing this on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/jU3tK3/1)

Regex: `^\+([0-9A-Za-z-]+)(?:\.([0-9A-Za-z-]+))*$`

Test string: `+beta-bar.baz-bz.fd.zz`

The string matches, but the "match information" box shows that there are only two capture groups:

`` MATCH 1
1.  [1-9]   `beta-bar`
2.  [20-22] `zz` ``

I was expecting all these captures:

1. beta-bar
2. baz-bz
3. fd
4. zz

Why didn't each identifier between periods get recognized as its own captured group?

Comment: Explanation is easy: only the last repetition of the capture group is stored in the buffer because you use `*` quantifier. You can just split the string with `[+.]` pattern.

Comment: If you want the captured matches in four groups, you need to write the pattern out to match the entire string,  i.e [`^\+([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/yQ9xM7/1)

Comment: Capture groups are determined statically: The first `(` in the regex starts group 1, the second `(` starts group 2, etc.

Comment: Thanks, all. There can be *n* groups, so I can't hard-code it. I guess regex can't express (and capture) the full semver-spec while automatically capturing each identifier. :(

Comment: stribizhev's answer is correct, though it's worth commenting that [tag:.net] does in fact return a collection of all captures matched by a capturing group. See `Group.Captures` Property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures(v=vs.110).aspx ... Please add the tag of your programming language since it's important to know the regex flavour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why that happens is because when using a quantifier on a capture group and it is captured *n* times, only the last captured text gets stored in the buffer and returned at the end.

Instead of matching those parts, you can `preg_split` the string you have with a simple regex `[+.]`:

```
$str = "+beta-bar.baz-bz.fd.zz";
$a = preg_split('/[+.]/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/21Famu)

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => beta-bar
    [1] => baz-bz
    [2] => fd
    [3] => zz
)
```

Comment: I have just realized I assumed you were using PHP. If t is, please add the tag to the question.